# lista preorden con recursividad en python

Tags: python

```
arbol1=[2,[7,[2,[],[]],[6,[5,[],[]],[11,[],[]]]],[5,[],[9,[4,[],[]],[]]]]
arbol2=[8,[3,[1,[],[]],[6,[4,[],[]],[7,[],[]]]],[10,[],[14,[13,[],[]],[]]]]
def raizArbin(a):
    return a[0]
def izqArbin(a):
    return a[1]
def derArbin(a):
    return a[2]
def vacioArbin(a):
    return a == []
def preordenLista(arbin,lista=[]):
    if not vacioArbin(arbin):
        x=raizArbin(arbin)
        lista.append(x)
        preordenLista(izqArbin(arbin))
        preordenLista(derArbin(arbin))
    return lista
def preordenLista2(arbin,lista=[]):
    if not vacioArbin(arbin):
        x=raizArbin(arbin)
        lista.append(x)
        preordenLista(izqArbin(arbin))
        preordenLista(derArbin(arbin))
    return lista
lista1=preordenLista(arbol1)
print lista1
lista2=preordenLista(arbol2)
print lista2
```

tengo el siguiente codigo que en teoria deberia mostrar una lista con el preorden de los arboles 1 y 2 pero al ejecutar una vez todo va normal y me muestra la lista [2, 7, 2, 6, 5, 11, 5, 9, 4] que es el preorden del primer arbol pero al mandar a la funcion el arbol2  me muestra [2, 7, 2, 6, 5, 11, 5, 9, 4, 8, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7, 10, 14, 13], no se por que se agrgan los del arbol 1 al arbol 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es bastante difícil de explicar, pero la causa está en el argumento por defecto que has dado a la función:

```
def preordenLista(arbin,lista=[]):
```

Resulta que esa lista que asignas `[]`, es siempre la misma, en todas las llamadas a la función. Por eso puedes ir acumulando en ella aunque no la pases como parámetro. Pero eso implica que la segunda vez que llamas a la función la lista aún tiene el valor de la ejecución anterior. Para entenderlo hazte a la idea de que esa lista vacía es una especie de variable global.

Este comportamiento un tanto inesperado se demuestra fácilmente, por ejemplo así:

```
>>> def ejemplo(elemento, lista=[]):
...    lista.append(elemento)
...    return lista
>>> ejemplo(1)
[1]
>>> ejemplo(2)
[1, 2]
```

### Soluciones:

La más directa sería no dar un valor por defecto a esa lista, sino pasarlo como parámetro en todas las llamadas:

```
def preordenLista(arbin,lista):
    if not vacioArbin(arbin):
        x=raizArbin(arbin)
        lista.append(x)
        preordenLista(izqArbin(arbin), lista)
        preordenLista(derArbin(arbin), lista)
    return lista
```

y naturalmente la lista vacía la pasarías en la primera llamada, desde el programa principal:

```
lista1=preordenLista(arbol1, [])
print lista1
lista2=preordenLista(arbol2, [])
print lista2
```

Si quieres evitar tener que pasar una lista vacía desde el programa principal, pues reconozco que la API queda "fea", puedes usar el siguiente truco en la función recursiva:

```
def preordenLista(arbin,lista=None):
    if lista is None:
        lista = []
    if not vacioArbin(arbin):
        x=raizArbin(arbin)
        lista.append(x)
        preordenLista(izqArbin(arbin), lista)
        preordenLista(derArbin(arbin), lista)
    return lista
```

De este modo puedes no pasar el segundo parámetro al llamarla, y se creará una lista vacía. Ya que esa lista se crea dentro de la función, será una nueva cada vez que la función sea invocada sin el segundo parámetro, y así no se "contaminan" las ejecuciones unas con otras.